# Chart.js Bar Chart - how to chart bars from 0

Tags: chart.js

I'd like to chart the bars extending from zero so that positive numbers grow upwards (as normal) but negative numbers grow downwards from zero. I get instead all numbers starting from a negative baseline.

Answer (score 50):

The other answers didn't work for me. However, I did manage to find another config option that did work for me.

```
var options = {
    // All of my other bar chart option here
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);
```

Passing this for my chart options give me a bar chart with the scale starting at 0.

Comment: Just as a note to anybody struggling with this problem. Make sure your yAxes object is inside of an array. e.g `yAxes: [{}]` instead of `yAxes: {}`. While the latter works, for some reason it doesn't apply the beginAtZero option.

Answer (score 10):

```
public barChartOptions: any = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true}
            }]
        },
     }
```

Answer (score 6):

use beginat zero like below:

```
options: {
     scales: {
         yAxes: [{
             ticks: {
                 beginAtZero:true
             }
         }]
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like this

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fkc5jt7/)

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, -30]
        }
    ]
};

var options = {
    scaleBeginAtZero: false
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);
```

Comment: I think you meant `{ scaleBeginAtZero: true }`, which gives partially the effect I wanted. However, the y-axis does not begin below -30. When I tried `options = { scaleOverride: true, scaleStartValue: -50, scaleStepWidth: 50, scaleSteps: 3, scaleBeginAtZero: true, }`, then then bars all spring from the bottom again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Chart.js version 2.0.2 and this could be achieved using `yAxes.min`, and if the chart is empty you could use `yAxes.suggestedMax`

Example:

```
options:{
    .
    .
    .
    scales{
        yAxes:[{
            min:0,
            //this value will be overridden if the scale is greater than this value
            suggestedMax:10
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
scales: {
  y: {
    beginAtZero: true
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use d3.js for the intended behaviour. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/slnader/9452976) is a good post regarding that.
Or
You can also follow this [article](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/working-with-negative-plotkit-chart-y-axis-values.html#fbid=ioFb2e0pgu6) tweaking the plotkit chart to show the downwards negative bar.

To make it work it with chart.js(though not advisable as this is not supported in Chart.js) you can use this github [pull](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/pull/669) and instead of using the global configuration object, i.e. setting:

```
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
Chart.defaults.global.scaleBeginAtZero = false;
Chart.defaults.global.barBeginAtOrigin = false,
Chart.defaults.global.animation = false;
```

use a separate config object and pass it into the chart constructor:

```
var chartOptions = {
    responsive:true,
    scaleBeginAtZero:false,
    barBeginAtOrigin:true
}
var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx).Bar(myChartData, chartOptions);
```